# compound interest amount

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Find the compound interest on a principal of:

$\$6540$ at $6\%$ p.a. for $4.5$ years.

I did:

$T= 6540(1+6\%)^{4.5}$ to get $8500.69$

I have been told the answer is wrong though. What have I done which is incorrect?

Thanks

Comment: How often is it compounded?

Comment: 4.5 years, sorry I forgot to include htat

Comment: Is $4.5$ years the amount of time that has passed or is it compounded every $4.5$ years?

Comment: it's being compounded every 4.5 years

Comment: The abbreviation p.a. means per annum, that is, interest is being compounded once per year.  You should have written $T = \$6540(1 + 0.06)^{4.5} = \$8500.69$.

Comment: The answer 8500.69 is the amount in the account after 4.5 years (if a half-year's interest is applied at withdrawal). However, the question asks for the _interest_ earned. So the answer is $8500.69-6540=1960.69$.